# Where can I find Microsoft.BusinessData.Infrastructure.SecureStore

Tags: 2013, secure-store

I'm trying to access Secure Store credentials through C# but I can't find the assembly any where in /15 or my GAC. You would think this would be easy if it was a best practice. Any ideas where I can find the DLL so I can run this code?

```
ISecureStoreProvider provider = SecureStoreProviderFactory.Create();
```

Comment: Look forMicrosoft.BusinessData.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, new 2013 location in 2013 is:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL
```

Comment: That is the GAC location. If the assembly is available there you should be able add reference it through 'add reference'->.Net tab

Comment: One remark, not all assemblies which are located in GAC are automatically available in 'Add Reference=>.NET'.

Comment: for sure... this would be one of them